# Unable To Sell NFT Functionality When deployed to Polygon

Tags: next.js, blockchain, ethereum, polygon, solidity

I recently launch NFT on Polygon main net.  I tested before on testnet, local, and Mumbai testnet.  I was able to buy, sell, and create my own NFT.

Problem:
After deployed the smart contract on the polygon main network I am unable to sell my own NFT functionality.

Technology stack:
Javascript, Ethereum, React, solidity and Next.js

Error
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any settings for the ChanID for Testnet is 80001, for the mainnet is 137. Need more details of what NFT marketplace are you using. You can try to import your smartcontract in Opensea and try to buy from there